# How to remove 1 element from 1 list and add to it into another one. Repeat this for the entire list

Tags: python, list

I have a List of element:

```
L = [1,2,3]
```

I would like to pop element from list L and add them to another list L2:

I am trying the following code:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    L2.append(L.pop())
```

But is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working?" Did you try putting `L2 = []` before `for` loop? Or do you want `L2` to be `[1,2,3]` instead of `[3,2,1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean not working, I put in your code to debug it and see what error it gives. But your code works fine.

```
L = [1,2,3]
L1 = []

print(L)
for i in range(len(L)):
    L1.append(L.pop())
print(L1)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Also of course by popping elements you get a reverse list, if you want the exact same list, you just do `L1 = L` or in the for loop just go `L1.append(L[i])`